# How can you assign a variable a value inside a if statement in Java

Tags: java

I need to do something like this,

```
if (first_var > second_var)
  int difference = first_var - second_var;
if (first_var < second_var)
  int difference = second_var - first_var;
```

When I try to compile this, an error comes stating the variable 'difference' may not have been initialized. Making the variable 'difference' global doesn't help either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The issues that you need to learn are:

- The scope of variables
- Block declaration and how that creates new scopes
- Why you should prefer to use `{...}` block for `if` statements
- How to guarantee definite assignment
- When to use `if-else` instead of `if (something) {...} if (!something) {...}`

By the way, the idiomatic way to find the difference of two values is:

```
int difference = Math.abs(firstVar - secondVar);
```

Do note that `Math.abs` has a corner case: when the argument is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the returned value is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. That's because `-Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE`. The issue here is 32-bit two's complement representation of numbers.

#### References

- [JLS 16 Definite Assignment](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/defAssign.html)
- [JLS 14.4.2 Scope of Local Variable Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.4.2)
- [JLS 14.9.2 The if-then-else Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.9.2)
- [`Math.abs(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29)
- [Wikipedia/Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (read: the most negative number)

---

#### Attempt #1: Declaring before the `if`

Here's one attempt to fix the snippet, by declaring the variable before the `if`

```
int difference;
if (first_var > second_var) {
  difference = first_var - second_var;
}
if (first_var < second_var) {
  difference = second_var - first_var;
}

// note: difference is not definitely assigned here!
//           (but at least it's in scope!)
```

We now have a problem with definite assignment: if `first_var == second_var`, the variable `difference` is still not assigned a value.

---

#### Attempt #2: Initializing at declaration

Here's a second attempt:

```
int difference = 0;
if (first_var > second_var) {
  difference = first_var - second_var;
}
if (first_var < second_var) {
  difference = second_var - first_var;
}

// note: difference is in scope here, and definitely assigned
```

Beginners tend to do this, but this precludes the possibility of making `difference` a `final` local variable, because it's possibly assigned value twice.

---

#### Attempt #3: `if-else`

Here's a better attempt:

```
final int difference;
if (first_var > second_var) {
  difference = first_var - second_var;
} else {
  difference = second_var - first_var;
}

// note: difference is in scope, and is definitely assigned here,
//       (and declared final)
```

There are still ways to improve on this.

---

#### Attempt #4: The ternary/conditional operator

Once you're more comfortable with the language and programming, you may use the following idiom:

```
final int difference = (first_var > second_var) ? first_var - second_var
                                                : second_var - first_var;
```

This uses the `?:` ternary/conditional operator. Do be careful with this operator; it has some behaviors that may be surprising, and it definitely can be abused. Use carefully, judiciously, idiomatically.

#### References

- [JLS 15.25 Conditional Operator `?:`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25)

Comment: Using `{...}` is a style choice. Of course, you can get the dangling-else problem if you are not careful, but then the lesson is just to be careful when you do omit the `{...}` :)

Comment: @Peter Alexander Formatting and indentation is a style choice too... see what I mean? ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. Do the condition on one line using the ternary operator ?:

   ```
   int difference = first_var > second_var ? first_var - second_var : second_var - first_var;
   ```
2. Declare the variable up front, then do the condition.

   ```
   int difference = 0;
   if (first_var > second_var)
     difference = first_var - second_var;
   if (first_var < second_var)
     difference = second_var - first_var;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can only declare a variable in one place.

The basic solution is

```
int difference;
if (first_var > second_var)
  difference = first_var - second_var;
if (first_var < second_var)
  difference = second_var - first_var;
```

However in this case you can use inline ?: operator

```
int difference = (first_var > second_var) ? 
  first_var - second_var : second_var - first_var;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because the variable might indeed not get initialized. In reality if `first_var` and `second_var` are equal to each other, it wouldn't get initialized. In addition to that, the compiler probably isn't smart enough to figure it out even if you added a third `if`. Move the declaration outside the `if`s and initialize it to a value on that line as well.

```
int difference = 0;
if (first_var > second_var)
    difference = first_var - second_var;
if (first_var < second_var)
    difference = second_var - first_var;
```

However, I'd just do

```
int difference = Math.abs(first_var - second_var);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to define tour variable "difference" outside your ifs statements:

```
int difference;
if (first_var > second_var)
    difference = first_var - second_var;
if (first_var < second_var)
    difference = second_var - first_var;
```

Then, the compiler can't be sure that your variable will have a value once both ifs statements are executed. For example, if first_var and second_var have the same value, difference will not be assigned. So, if you try to use your variable, you'll have a compile time error.

To resolve this, you have two solutions:

The first solution is to give your variable a default value, which will be used if no other conditions is completed:

```
int difference = 0;
if (first_var > second_var)
    difference = first_var - second_var;
if (first_var < second_var)
    difference = second_var - first_var;
```

The other solution is to use else if statements. When using else if statements, the compiler is able to determine if your variable will be assigned in all cases:

```
int difference;
if (first_var > second_var) {
    difference = first_var - second_var;
} else if (first_var < second_var) {
    difference = second_var - first_var;
} else {
    difference = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed assign a variable inside an if statement, but you cannot initialize it inside an if statement.  In plain English, you can give a variable a value inside an if statement, but you cannot create a variable inside an if statement.  The reason for this is because there is a possibility that the code inside the if statement will never run if the if conditions are never met.

Here's how I would have written that code:

```
int difference = 0;

if (first_var > second_var)
   difference = first_var - second_var;
else if (first_var < second_var)
   difference = second_var - first_var;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it may not have been initialized is you accounted for A < B, B < A, but not A == B.  Account for that:

```
if (first_var > second_var)
  int difference = first_var - second_var;
if (first_var < second_var)
  int difference = second_var - first_var;
if (first_var == second_var)
  int difference = 0;
```