# Create Object in if-statement and use it later

Tags: java, object, if-statement

I am writing a Parser for Infix Notation.
In the if-statement I declare the variable newchild. Otherwise I want it to throw an exception. But when I am out of the scope the Compiler does not know the variable anymore. 
I cannot declare it before the if-statement, because the variable gets assigned a different data type depending on the case we are in.

What can I do to fix this?

```
public class ParserForInfixNotation {

public Node parse(List<String> tokenList) {

    Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<String>();
    int i =1;
    while(i <= tokenList.size()){                           //wir gehen alle Eintraege in der Liste durch
        if(Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(i).charAt(1))){
            int value = Integer.parseInt(tokenList.get(i));     //falls der Eintrag eine Zahl ist, wird ein neuer Leaf erstellt
            Leaf res = new Leaf(value);
        }
        else if(tokenList.get(i) == "("){                       // falls der Eintrag eine Klammer ist, wird geschaut, ob in der Klammer ein Unary oder Binary OpNode definiert ist
            if (tokenList.get(i+1) == "-") {
                                                                // Fall Unary
                int j = i+1;
                                                                //am Liebsten ein rekursiver Aufruf auf parser mit nem TeilString des Oberen Strings, der genau den naechsten Node beschreibt
                int anzahlklammern = 0;
                boolean end = false;
                if((Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(j).charAt(1))) || (tokenList.get(j+1) == ")")){
                    Leaf newchild = new Leaf(Integer.parseInt(tokenList.get(j)));
                }
                else if(tokenList.get(j) == "("){
                    while(!end){
                        if(tokenList.get(j) == ")" && anzahlklammern == 1){
                            end = true;
                        }
                        else if(tokenList.get(j) == ")" && j > i+3){                    //die Klammer muss mindestens 2 Stellen enthalten
                            anzahlklammern--;
                            j++;
                        }
                        else if(tokenList.get(j) == "("){
                            anzahlklammern++;
                            j++;
                        }
                        else if ((Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(j).charAt(1))) || tokenList.get(j) == "+" || tokenList.get(j) == "*" || tokenList.get(j) == "-"){
                            j++;
                        }
                        else{
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                        }
                    }
                    List<String> neu = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int l = i+2; l<j;l++){
                        neu.add(tokenList.get(l));
                    }
                    Node newchild = parse(neu);
                }
                else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }

                UnaryOpNode res = new UnaryOpNode('-',newchild);
            }
            else if((tokenList.get(i+1) == "(") || (Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(i+1).charAt(1)))){ //Fall Binary
                if (Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(i+1).charAt(1)) && (tokenList.get(i+2) == "+" || tokenList.get(i+2) == "*")){
                    Leaf newchildleft = new Leaf(Integer.parseInt(tokenList.get(i+1)));
                    if(tokenList.get(i+2) == "+"){
                        Character operator = '+';
                    }
                    else if(tokenList.get(i+2) == "*"){
                        Character operator = '*';
                    }
                    int j = i+3;
                    if(Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(j).charAt(1))){
                        Leaf newchildright = new Leaf(Integer.parseInt(tokenList.get(j)));
                    }
                    else if(tokenList.get(j) == "("){
                        boolean end = false;
                        int anzahlklammern =0 ;
                        while(!end){
                            if(tokenList.get(j) == ")" && anzahlklammern == 1){
                                end = true;
                            }
                            else if(tokenList.get(j) == ")" && j > i+5){                    //die Klammer muss mindestens 2 Stellen enthalten
                                anzahlklammern--;
                                j++;
                            }
                            else if(tokenList.get(j) == "("){
                                anzahlklammern++;
                                j++;
                            }
                            else if ((Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(j).charAt(1))) || tokenList.get(j) == "+" || tokenList.get(j) == "*" || tokenList.get(j) == "-"){
                                j++;
                            }
                            else{
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                            }
                        }
                        List<String> neu = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int l = i+4; l<j;l++){
                            neu.add(tokenList.get(l));
                        }
                        Node newrightchild = parse(neu);
                    }
                    else{
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    }
                }
                else if(tokenList.get(i+1) == "("){
                    int j= i+1;
                    boolean end = false;
                    int anzahlklammern =0 ;
                    while(!end){
                        if(tokenList.get(j) == ")" && anzahlklammern == 1){
                            end = true;
                        }
                        else if(tokenList.get(j) == ")" && j > i+3){                    //die Klammer muss mindestens 2 Stellen enthalten
                            anzahlklammern--;
                            j++;
                        }
                        else if(tokenList.get(j) == "("){
                            anzahlklammern++;
                            j++;
                        }
                        else if ((Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(j).charAt(1))) || tokenList.get(j) == "+" || tokenList.get(j) == "*" || tokenList.get(j) == "-"){
                            j++;
                        }
                        else{
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                        }
                    }
                    List<String> neu = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int l = i+2; l<j;l++){
                        neu.add(tokenList.get(l));
                    }
                    Node newleftchild = parse(neu);
                    if(tokenList.get(j+1) == "+"){
                        Character operator = '+';
                    }
                    else if(tokenList.get(j+1) == "*"){
                        Character operator = '*';
                    }
                    else{
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    }
                    if(tokenList.get(j+2)== "("){
                        int k= j+3;
                        end = false;
                        anzahlklammern =0 ;
                        while(!end){
                            if(tokenList.get(k) == ")" && anzahlklammern == 1){
                                end = true;
                            }
                            else if(tokenList.get(k) == ")" && k > j+5){                    //die Klammer muss mindestens 2 Stellen enthalten
                                anzahlklammern--;
                                k++;
                            }
                            else if(tokenList.get(k) == "("){
                                anzahlklammern++;
                                k++;
                            }
                            else if ((Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(k).charAt(1))) || tokenList.get(k) == "+" || tokenList.get(k) == "*" || tokenList.get(k) == "-"){
                                k++;
                            }
                            else{
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                            }
                        }
                        List<String> neu2 = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int l = j+4; l<k;l++){
                            neu.add(tokenList.get(l));
                        }
                        Node newrightchild = parse(neu2);
                    }
                    else if(Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(j+2).charAt(1))){
                        Leaf newrightchild = new Leaf(Integer.parseInt(tokenList.get(j+2)));
                    }
                    else{
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    }
                }
                BinaryOpNode res = new BinaryOpNode(operator, newleftchild, newrightchild);
            }
            else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }



    return res; 
}
```

Comment: Declare it in whatever scope you want to be able to use it in. You can assign it a value (or not) inside your if-statement, then check against a null value when you come to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you assign a variable a value inside a if statement in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594427/how-can-you-assign-a-variable-a-value-inside-a-if-statement-in-java)

Comment: Why dont you move that "later use" inside the `if` block?

Comment: what is the relationship between Leaf & Node. If there is parent-child relationship, then just declare a variable of parent type outside of "if" block, and initiate it inside block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about *scope*. A variable's scope is the block in which it is *declared*, and blocks within that. It doesn't matter whether the block is the block of an `if` statement, some other statement, or just a block put there for the purpose of defining scope.

You are experiencing this:

```
{
    Leaf leaf = new Leaf();
}

doSomethingWith(leaf); // compiler error - there is no `leaf` in this scope.
```

You can fix it with:

```
 Leaf leaf;
 {
      leaf = new Leaf();
 }
 doSomethingWith(leaf);
```

If there is a possibility that the assignment to `leaf` won't happen -- for example if it's in an `if` block, then you'll get a compiler error saying `variable leaf may not have been initialized`. You can fix this by initialising to some fallback value first. It's often null:

```
 Leaf leaf = null;
 if(...) {
      leaf = new Leaf();
 }
 doSomethingWith(leaf);
```

But now your code has to cope with the possibility that `leaf == null` - and this leads to code that's either over-complex or fragile. Find ways to avoid ever assigning null, or if you can't, keep the vulnerable block of code isolated, so that nothing outside that scope needs to deal with the possibility of a null variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
int value = = -1;
Leaf res = null;
if(Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(i).charAt(1))){
      value =Integer.parseInt(tokenList.get(i));                
      res = new Leaf(value);
 }
```

and check out of the ***if***  what values are stored in the variables ***value*** and ***res***

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to move / copy this line :

```
UnaryOpNode res = new UnaryOpNode('-',newchild);
```

So that it is contained within both the If and the else if like this:

```
if((Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(j).charAt(1))) || (tokenList.get(j+1) == ")"))
{
    Leaf newchild = new 
    Leaf(Integer.parseInt(tokenList.get(j)));
    UnaryOpNode res = new UnaryOpNode('-',newchild);
}
else if(tokenList.get(j) == "("){
    while(!end){
        if(tokenList.get(j) == ")" && anzahlklammern == 1){
            end = true;
        }
        else if(tokenList.get(j) == ")" && j > i+3){   
            anzahlklammern--;
            j++;
        }
        else if(tokenList.get(j) == "("){
            anzahlklammern++;
            j++;
        }
        else if ((Character.isDigit(tokenList.get(j).charAt(1))) || tokenList.get(j) == "+" || tokenList.get(j) == "*" || tokenList.get(j) == "-"){
            j++;
        }
        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
    List<String> neu = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int l = i+2; l<j;l++){
        neu.add(tokenList.get(l));
    }
    Node newchild = parse(neu);
    UnaryOpNode res = new UnaryOpNode('-',newchild);
}
else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```